# C# Unit Test on Textbox Input from user

Tags: c#, unit-testing, textbox

I would like to create an automatic `C#` unit test to test textboxes and properties of an object.

These are the properties of the Customer object:

```
public int CustomerId { get; set; }
public string FirstName { get; set; }
public string LastName { get; set; }
public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
```

These are the textboxes that receive data from user:

```
Convert.ToInt32(txtBoxCustomerId.Text),
txtBoxCustomerFirstName.Text,
txtBoxCustomerLastName.Text,
txtBoxCustomerEmailAddress.Text);
```

The textboxes are in the `Form1.cs` Class and the Customer properties are in the `customer.cs` Class. I would like to know how to create automated unit tests to check if the user inputs the correct data type in these textboxes.

Thank you!.

Comment: How can you unit test what a user does?  Do you mean _validate_ the data?  Or you want to create a unit test to ensure that the textboxes are bound to the right class properties?

Comment: Yes D Stanley, I believe you are right. I would like to validate data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could pass the data directly to the form in form1.cs and than to check your Data model is correct at some point down the chain.
in a web application you could input the data with selenium and test the DTO down the chain- in desktop might be there is some UI automation too.